# When do method references work?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, method-reference, assertj

Method references don't work with non-static methods AFAIK. I tried using them in the [following way](https://ideone.com/O1wtD7)

```
Arrays.stream(new Integer[] {12,321,312}).map(Integer::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which resulted in the compilation error as seen in the link.

[image: Picture for error]

**Problem**
While using `AssertJ` library, I used something like this,

```
AbstractObjectAssert<?, Feed> abstractObjectAssertFeed2 = assertThat(feedList.get(2));
abstractObjectAssertFeed2.extracting(Feed::getText).isEqualTo(new Object[] {Constants.WISH+" HappyLife"});
```

where `Feed` is a noun and `getText` is a getter method and *not static*, but it worked fine without compilation error or any error which puzzled me.

[image: Proof not a static method.]

Am I missing something about how method references work?

Comment: You don't really need to map an `Integer` to `String` if you want to print stream content. `Arrays.stream(new Integer[] {12,321,312}).forEach(System.out::println);`  works fine.

Comment: and you can just use `.map(Object::toString)` instead of `.map(Integer::toString)`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc It was a test. I was prototyping to confirm how method references work and unfortunately (or is it really) faced this problem (which I thought was real) with error message I expected. What are the odds!

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc should I still say that question which you marked solved my problem when I didn't face the same problem and it turned out to be same?

Comment: You should not ignore the “**2 errors**” footer line, which indicates that you ignored another error upfront. Generally, with the current compiler, if you see two error messages, “non-static method … cannot be referenced from a static context” and another error, focus on “another error” first. It’ll save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is invalid for a different reason.

Basically there are two `toString` implementations in `Integer`.

```
static toString(int)
```

and

```
/*non- static*/ toString()
```

Meaning you could write your stream like this:

```
 Arrays.stream(new Integer[] { 12, 321, 312 })
       .map(i -> i.toString(i))
       .forEach(System.out::println);

Arrays.stream(new Integer[] { 12, 321, 312 })
       .map(i -> i.toString())
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Both of these qualify as a method reference via `Integer::toString`. The first one is a method reference to a `static method`. And the second is `Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type`.

Since they both qualify the compiler does not know which to choose.

Comment: Isn't first one `Integer.toString(i)`?

Comment: @TarunMaganti yes I could have written it like this too (without getting the warning), but I thought it's easier for you to get the point here...

Comment: So, it's due to ambiguity then. If you could add picture of the table It would be much more helpful - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Ok. Got it. I forgot that objects can be used to access static methods.